# Display multiple images from mysql with php

Tags: php, html, image

I've successfully added images path in database, but unable to display images on webpage. I want to make a gallery with the help of images array. Anybody help me in this regard, how can i achieve this. Here is my code sample.

```
<?php




        $mac_ID = 2;



     $getmachine_qry = "SELECT * FROM MACHINES inner Join Images on machines.id=images.fk_mac_id and fk_mac_id=$mac_ID";

    $run_getmachine_qry = mysqli_query($db_con, $getmachine_qry);

    while($row_getmachine = mysqli_fetch_array($run_getmachine_qry)){

       // $machine_ID = $row_getmachine['id'];
        $machine_title = $row_getmachine['machine_title'];
        $machine_year = $row_getmachine['year'];
        $machine_price = $row_getmachine['price'];
        $machine_detail = $row_getmachine['detail'];
        $machine_img = $row_getmachine['image'];



?>
        <img src="<?php echo $row_getmachine['image'] ?>" style="width:100px"/>

  <?php
    }?>
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Did you check the image path?

Comment: Might help: [Relative and absolute paths, in the file system and on the web server](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths)

Comment: What does `$row_getmachine['image']` show?

Comment: $row_getmachine['image'] can echo image path successfully. But may be problem with img tag. If i put this in img tag then no action.

Comment: img tag is working successfully with single path but when i put database images array it does not work. I've 3 to 10 images in that array.

Comment: What do you mean with "images array"? If you have an entry for each image in `Images` and the field `Images.image` contains the string to the image path, then your code should work, no matter how many images you have: The SQL will return a row for each Image, not for each machine. Which means your `while` actually loops through images, not machines.

Comment: Yes images array means, path of every image. I don't know why it is not working with img tag.

Comment: If i put this <img src="<?php echo $row_getmachine['image'] ?>" /> outside from src attribute will show all images path but no action within img tag.